# Rails - Named scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

for my user's model I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => 'select DISTINCT u.* from users u join permissions pp on pp.user_id=u.id join spaces p on pp.space_id=p.id where space_id in (select space_id from permissions pp2 where user_id=#{id}) and pp.user_id != #{id}'
```

How can I access that in a scope like:

```
  scope :usersInMySpaces, lambda { |user|
      group_users
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Just so you know: http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

Comment: Also, in Ruby community we prefer underscores for method names, variables, symbols (everything except class names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and there's no point. `has_many` associations act like scopes in many cases but in this one the finder_sql is so complicated that it couldn't be combined with any other sql as a scope.